# Scaladoc reference documentation - does it exist?

Tags: scaladoc

I'm looking for anything that can be used as a full reference on scaladoc tags (at least).

Web search gives just [a style guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html), an overview [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/overview.html) and [differences between dotty(scala3) scaladoc and the old one](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/usage/scaladoc/index.html). No complete list of tags. A lot of tags are just mentioned by name with no other information at all.

Sometimes, when there is no documentation, the source code can be used instead. But I can't find the scaladoc source code too. Is it a some deep-buried part of the scala compiler code or what? If documentation does not exist, I would be grateful for a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what scala do you target? For scala 2.13.X source code can be found [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.13.x/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/nsc/doc) and for scala 3 source code is located [here](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/tree/master/scaladoc)

If you want to take a look at scala 2.13.X tags I guess you were very close with your search, take a look at this [page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scaladoc/for-library-authors.html), does it answers you questions? Sadly for scala 3 there is no updated docs yet, though I hope in the following week I will merge updated docs, which will include tags manual, however they should be 100% compatible with old scaladoc syntax.